# Fixed scrolling object (CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to ask a question, the thing is that I know a little CSS and a little bit of jQuery. What I'm trying to do is put a FB like button on my page, when the viewer scrolls the page and the button reaches the top, it should be fixed at the top as the viewer scrolls and if the viewer scrolls back up, it should return to its original position. I've tried `position:fixed;` and `position:absolute;` but they don't work as expected. I read somewhere that I will have to use javascript to achieve this but can I do it with CSS + jQuery because those are what I can understand easily. Please visit this link: http://bit.ly/19INM0r and look at the like and twitter button on the left and how they react when you scroll, that's what I want to do.

Comment: jQuery is javascript, I know that but it's easier and the link is a demo page, please read what I wrote. As I said I've tried everything and the two codes I used for positioning, as mentioned above, have got me nowhere. I just need a sample, a really simple sample to do this with CSS and jQuery.

Comment: Look at this JS plugin:http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: The link is not of my website, it takes you to a website where I have seen the scrolling effect in action and I want to do it. The buttons scroll up when the viewer scrolls down and when the buttons reach the top they get fixed at the top until the viewer scrolls back up again

Comment: @StefanDunn that's what I want to do, thanks for the link. I'm at work right now, I'll try it later and post the result here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good plugin to do what you wan't http://stickyjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

`position: sticky;` is what you're after. [Here's an overview on the new feature that includes a backwards compatible solution](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit).

Comment: This is experimental... take care about browser compability

Comment: @ViníciusMoraes There's a simple polyfill included in the resource I linked to that doesn't depend on any JS frameworks. There's no risk in using experimental CSS properties/values. Browsers will simply ignore anything they don't support.

Comment: That's amazing, it would be a lot better using only CSS. I'll try both the JS plugin and this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AndréDion I couldn't find the polyfill, can you get the link for me ?

Comment: @ViníciusMoraes It's in the [article I linked to](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit). If you're looking for something pre-packaged, you could try [Googling it](https://www.google.ca/#q=position+sticky+polyfill)...